# Cron job to back up mysql

Tags: mysql, backup, cron

I have a Fedora server with a USB backup drive connected to it.  I have managed to mount the drive and want to run a daily backup of my MySql database.  I am completely new to cron jobs and really need some help please.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [crontab syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#crontab_syntax) is really easy to understand. Just try it.

For the backup of your MySQL databases you could just use `mysqldump` which is shipped with MySQL. There are more sophisticated means of making backups of a MySQL database but `mysqldump` should just do fine for you.

Comment: Thanks for response, so if I type the following into the shell it should back up the db 1 minute past 12.

1 0 * * * mysqldump -u -p [database] > /usbdrive/bk.sql

If this is right how would I set the dates in the .sql file name?

Cheers

Comment: You could use `date` for this, e. g. `/usr/bin/mysqldump -u [user] -p [pass] [database] > /usbdrive/backup-$(date +'\%F').sql`.

Comment: Cheers joschi, added it to crontab and tested it every 5 mins and working so now set it to 1 minute past 12 o'clock at night so hopefully it will work.   Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

On top of what joschi said, once you use `mysqldump` to generate the backup file, you can do a lot of other things with it.

What I used to do was to email myself the database as an attachment using `mutt`, daily. Of course this depends on the size of your databases but it did give me an off-site backup solution.